# docker-compose not producting "No Such File or Directory" when files exist in container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a simple Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install

RUN apt-get install -y \
    curl \
    gcc \
    make \
    python3-psycopg2 \
    postgresql-client \
    libpq-dev

RUN mkdir -p /var/www/myapp
WORKDIR /var/www/myapp
COPY . /var/www/myapp

RUN chmod 700 ./scripts/*.sh
```

And an associated docker-compose file

```
version: "3"
volumes:
  postgresdata:
services:
  myapp:
    image: ralston3/myapp_api:prod-latest
    tty: true
    command: /bin/bash -c "/var/www/myapp/scripts/myscript.sh && echo 'hello world'"
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/myapp
    environment:
      SOME_ENV_VARS=SOME_VARIABLE
      # ... more here
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - postgresql
# ... other docker services defined below
```

When I run docker-compose up via:

```
docker-compose up -f /path/to/docker-compose.yml up
```

My `myapp` container/service fails with `myapp_myapp_1 exited with code 127` with another error mentioning `myapp_1     | /bin/sh: 1: /var/www/myapp/scripts/myscript.sh: not found`

Further, if I exec into the `myapp` container via `docker exec -it {CONTAINER_ID} /bin/bash` I can clearly see that all of my files are there. I can literally run the `/var/www/myapp/scripts/myscript.sh` and it works fine.

However, there seems to be some issue with docker-compose (which could totally be my mistake). But I'm just confused as to how I can exec into the container and clearly see the files there. But docker-compose exists with 127 saying "No such file or directory".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are bind mounting the current directory into "/var/www/myapp" so it may be that your local directory is "hiding/overwriting" the container directory. Try removing the volumes declaration for you myapp service and if that works then you know it is the bind mount causing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Unrelated to your question, but a problem you will also encounter: you're installing Python a second time, above and beyond the version pre-installed in the `python` Docker image.

Either switch to `debian:buster` as base image, or don't bother installing antyhign with apt-get and instead just pip install your dependencies like psycopg.

See https://pythonspeed.com/articles/official-python-docker-image/ for explanation why you don't need to do this.

Comment: Noted. Thanks. Was not aware that `python:3.8-slim-buster` included all of those packages already

Answer (score 0):

in my case there were 2 stages: builder and runner.

I was getting an executable in builder and running that exe using the alpine image in runner.

My mistake here was that I didn't use the alpine version for the builder. Ex. I used golang:1.20 but when I used golang:1.20-alpine the problem went away.

Make sure you use the correct version and tag!